# How to properly check resource usage of AWS EMR cluster(master and cores) from notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

Here are my cluster details:

```
Master : Running 1 m4.xlarge
Core : Running 3 m4.xlarge
Task : --
Cluster scaling: Not enabled
```

And I am using notebooks to practice pyspark. And I would like to know how the resources are being utilised, to assess if the resources are being under-utilised or not enough for my tasks. And part of which, when checking RAM/memory usage, here's what I got from terminal:

```
notebook@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~$ free -h
      total used free shared buff/cache available
Mem:  1.9G  456M 759M 72K    741M       1.4G
Swap: 0B    0B   0B
```

Each instance of m4.xlarge comes with 16GB of memory. What's happening and why is only two gigs of 16GB being shown? And How do I properly learn how much of my CPU, Memory and Storage are actually being used? (yes, to reduce costs!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check memory and CPU utilization you can check that in CloudWatch with the instance Id.

- To get the instance id of the node (*Hardware -> Instance Group -> Instances*).
  You can get detailed metrics of CPU, memory, IO for each node.

---

Another option to use resource manager UI (YARN). default url -> http://master-node-ip:8088.

You can get metrics on job level as well as node level.

Comment: In cloudwatch, under explorer, for EC2, I could find CPU utilisation, io, network, status checks, but not memory/RAM. Where do I get that?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot that shows the CPU/memory usage for each node on EMR? I can't find any of that on cloudwatch for the EMR instance id. Do we have to look under EC2 instead?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned you need to copy instance ID from EMR console, and then look metrics on `AWS/EC2` namespace per instance.

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala Memory utilization is something accessed at the OS level - not Hypervisor layer (like CPU and Network Utilization). As such, AWS doesn't have access to memory utilization by default. In order to view memory utilization, we have to install a CloudWatch Agent ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

To start reducing costs you can use m5 or m6g instances and also consider using spot instances. Also, you can use the metrics in EMR console in Monitoring tab. Container pending graph it's a good way to start monitoring. If you dpn't have any container pending and you have executors without tasks running inside you are wasting resources(CPU).

Comment: m5 instances have been out of capacity in my region(ap-south-1: Mumbai) for EMR clusters since more than a month. Thanks, I will try m6g instances now.

Comment: for 3 m6g instances(1 master + 2 core), I get maximum of 24% CPU usage in each instance. This clearly means, I can get away with using just 1 m6g instance, right?

Comment: Did you check container pending graph? Also, you can try to increase partitions to paralelize more the process.

Comment: No, I haven't checked container pending graph. TBH, I don't know where I can find it either. And by partitions do you mean partitions of all of my dataframes?

Comment: You can find this graph in EMR console, in monitoring tab. Yes, in your dataframes maybe you need to repartition to more partitions.